# string 'properties.dimensions.length' to access hash {properties: {dimensions: {length: 23}}}

Tags: javascript, node.js

JavaScript: given an array of strings:

```
 ['properties.dimensions.length', 'properties.name']
```

what would be the best way to use these to validate or access them (in fact just want to verify if the key does exist) in a hash?

I was thinking of string split('.') but I haven't been able to really understand how each of the array values could be used to validate or access the value from a hash.

like ['properties', 'dimensions', 'length'] and then forEach that to drill down, but ideally I'd like to turn that into the equiv of code:

```
myProperties['properties']['dimensions']['length']
```

But feel free to say if this is a totally hacky approach... and be nice! :-D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
function hasProperty(obj, props) {
    if (typeof props === "string") 
        return hasProperty(obj, props.split("."));
    for(var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
        if (props[i] in obj) 
            obj = obj[props[i]];
        else 
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var propPath = 'properties.dimensions.length';
console.log(hasProperty(myProperties, propPath));
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ybk2T/)

And here's a recursive alternative:

```
function hasProperty(obj, props) {
    if (typeof props === "string") 
        return hasProperty(obj, props.split('.'));
    return props.length == 0 || props[0] in obj && hasProperty(obj[props.shift()], props);
}

var propPath = 'properties.dimensions.length';
console.log(hasProperty(myProperties, propPath));
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ybk2T/1/)

Comment: +1, though I think a recursive function would be shorter and more readable

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn Added a recursive version for fun

Comment: It works! And quite nicely. You answered that almost before I submitted it! You work for the NSA or something? :-D  Many thanks!

Comment: @AndrewLank I answered a [question similar to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288006/access-nested-objects-via-array-of-property-names/21288088#21288088) the other day. I was tempted to close as a duplicate, but simply testing for a property's existence (rather than getting / setting the value) is different enough that I felt it warranted it's own answer.