# What's the proper way to check for deeply nested attributes in javascript?

Tags: javascript

A problem I constantly encounter in javascript is checking for the existence of a nested attribute or method before using it. I'm sure this topic is well covered on the interwebs, but I'd like to solicit feedback and improvements on my specific technique. There are a couple tricks I use when something is a single level deep:

```js
var a = { person: { name: 'jon' } };

console.log(a.person || 'No person found');
// Or
if (a.hasOwnProperty('person')) {
  console.log(a.person);
} else {
  console.log('No person found');
}
```

This works fine. Problems start creeping up when I am trying to access attributes that are deeper than one level.  I know of ways to handle this problem, but I am curious if this is the **best** way to go about it:

```js
if(a.hasOwnProperty('person') && a.person.hasOwnProperty('name')) {
  console.log(a.person.name);
} else {
  console.log('We're missing either the person, or their name');
}
```

I am defining **best** as the most *readable* and *error resistant*. I'm also aware that `hasOwnProperty` is an ES5 only function and that it helps protect against prototype pollution.

Thanks, friends!

Comment: If you're not expecting "null-like" values (0, "", false), you could simply do something like : if(!a.person) return "no person"; if(!a.person.name) return "no name";

Comment: Use a recursive has property method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21339804/140937

Comment: @p.s.w.g That could maybe be one possible answer, but the OP is asking about *safe mapping* (such as `?.` operators is other languages) rather than *mapping-by-string*.

Comment: @AlonGubkin that seems like a very elegant solution. As is usually the case in js, we just build it ourselves! Nice to know I wasn't missing something obvious.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Ahh, **that's** what it's called! I always wondered if there was a term for it.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski If all OP is interested in is to "*check for deeply nested attributes*" (from the title), then that method works. To safely navigate to that deeply nested property, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21288088/1715579

Comment: I think using a string or an array are the only two ways this could be possible. I vote for the string approach.

Comment: i wrote http://danml.com/js/oquery.js to try to make it as easy as using css selectors.

Comment: The only other thing you could do is wrap it in a `try {} catch` block everywhere it is used like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/RARma/)